# How to find folders in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cd

I'm new to Linux and just downloaded WSL2 and ubuntu on my Windows PC.
I started the Windows terminal, chose Ubuntu from there, and wanted to move to the Desktop by using cd.
However, I could not find the Desktop folder.
First, I did "ls /" and many folders labeled as the following appeared.
"bin", "dev", "home", "lib".....
Where is the Desktop folder? I moved to the "home" folder but there was nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSL mounts the windows filesystem under `/mnt/c`, try `/mnt/c/Users/<username>/desktop`.

Comment: Additionally, the `c` in `/mnt/c` is the drive letter. Others may use something different. Not every Windows / user directory installed in C...